# save canvas drawing as data or image for later insertion into html page

Tags: javascript, meteor

A Meteor client code renders a template with `canvas` for client signature.  It listens on `mousemove` and draws lines between mouse x,y coordinates of one point to another as it moves, using `context.stroke()`.

How can the signature be saved and inserted in html page later? i.e. data or image would be best practice? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a variable

```
var image = ctx.getImageData(0,0,width,height);
```

To put it back when you need it:

```
ctx.putImageData(imgdata, 0,0);
```

Comment: do you mean `var imgdata` so that it matches the second line of code to put it back when I need it?

Comment: Yeah. And I don't mean "width" and "height" unless you set those variables.